# Creating a page building framework in javascript utilizing customElements

Tags: javascript, custom-element, html-templates

Me and my friend are trying to make a javascript framework that allows users to make elements and customize them. As well as manage them somehow.

We were hoping that we could somehow make a custom element like this

```js
class Header extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();

  }

  connectedCallback(){

    this.title = this.getAttribute("title")
    console.log(this.getAttribute("title"))

    if(this.hasAttribute("drawer-button")){

    }

    this.innerHTML = 
      `
      <div class="--e-header-1">
        <e-button></e-button>
        <div class="header-title">
          <h1>${this.title}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      `
  }

}

customElements.define('e-header', Header);
```

its cool that you can use it in HTML like this `<e-header></e-header>` but we were hoping that we could do something like this

```js
var el = new Header(//put in options maybe);
document.append(el)
```

we keep getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor`

how would we go about doing something like this and are we on the right track

Comment: The error comes from `document.append(el)` which should be `document.body.append(el)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do something like this?

I have passed option `title` to the class and set that in the class.

```js
class Header extends HTMLElement {

  constructor(options) {
    super();
    this.title = options.title;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.title = this.getAttribute("title")
    console.log(this.getAttribute("title"))

    if (this.hasAttribute("drawer-button")) {

    }

    this.innerHTML =
      `
      <div class="--e-header-1">
        <e-button></e-button>
        <div class="header-title">
          <h1>${this.title}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      `
  }

}

customElements.define('e-header', Header);

var el = new Header({
  'title': 'headerTitle'
});
document.body.append(el)
```

Comment: This is exactly what we were looking for thank you very much.

Comment: More generic, do ``Object.assign(this,options)`` instead of hard coding ``this.title=options.title`` And you can set default values: ``constructor({title='No Title'})``